# Comparison of Poisson cumulative probabilities between models with different rates

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm building an anomaly detection model using the Poisson distribution.
I'm calculating the Cumulative Probability: P(X >= x) for thousands of count data, all of them with different rates.

I need to have a way to compare all those probabilities in a meaningful way.

As an example lets assume I have two event types, one with a expected rate of 1 and the other one with an expected rate of 2.

At the same time I have a real observed value of 2 for the first one and 4 for the second one so 100% more than the expected rate for both.

Using the Poisson model I get a Cumulative Probability: P(X >= 2) = 0.26424 for the first one with the expected rate of 1 but a Cumulative Probability: P(X >= 4) = 0.14287 for the one with the expected rate of 2. (a handy online poisson calculator is available here: https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/poisson.aspx)

This is a little counter intuitive for me and definitely a flow in my current implementation as the comparisons are unusable especially with high rates where a mismatch of let say observed 400 vs expected 200 gives the same Cumulative Probability as a super anomalous event happening for events with low rates.

I can of course adjust all parameters of the model and for example choose a common single rate for all my Poisson distributions by adjusting the observation intervals if that's a requirement.

A sample data could be:

```
timestamp,EventType
1,A
11,A
20,A
```

```
timestamp,EventType
1,B
5,B
11,B
13,B
16,B
18,B
```

Let say I use the interval from timestamp 1 to 10 as historic observations that I use to compute the expected rate and timescale 11 to 20 as the interval for which I'm calculating the Cumulative Probability of P(A >= 2) and P(B >= 4).
Both intervals do have the same length of 10 timestamps, so my expected rate is 1/10 x 10 = 1 and 2/10 x 10 = 2, my observed rate is 2 for the A event and 4 for the B event.

I didn't find anything clear enough online and I need to have a good understanding of the way two processes with different rates should be compared when they are modeled as a Poisson process and why.

Comment: Could you explain the data you are collecting?  Without some understanding of that, it will be difficult to determine what makes sense.  In particular, on what basis are you "calculating" cumulative probabilities and exactly what are you comparing to what?

Comment: I edited the post. Is it clearer with the sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is... as the mean of the Poisson gets larger, the spread gets larger too, but not proportionally to the mean, instead proportionally to the $\sqrt{\text{mean}}$, so what appears to puzzle you is actually expected behavior.

Comment: I'm not saying the behaviour is unexpected. It actually is. What I'm looking for is a meaningful way of comparison between the probabilities. Let say I need to set an anomaly threshold for my A and B EventTypes. I set the threshold at Cumulative Probability < 15%, the B sample will be considered anomaly while  the A sample won't. This of course can by pushed much further with much higher rates. So what now if I set the observation period of B to 11 to 15, the expected rate will be 2. Does it make sense? Or there is no way to compare the percentages and quantities based on history are required.

Comment: In my last sentence of the previous comment "quantities" need to be replaced by "percentiles".